# Node.js "Error: channel closed" on .send when child_process forked for the second time

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm having some issues whent trying to send data to a child process when it is forked for the second time.

Here's an sample code of what I'm trying to do:

```
var child_process = require("child_process");
var io = require("socket.io")(app); //app contains http server

var pageSocket = io.of('/somePage');

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    var child = child_process.fork('./sample.js');

    socket.on('some:event', function(){
        child.send({key: value});
    });     

    child.on('message', function(data){
        //Do something
    });

    child.on('exit', function(code, signal){
        if (signal === 'SIGTERM') {
            socket.emit('page:closed');
        }
    });

    socket.on('page:close', function(){
        child.kill("SIGTERM");
    });
});
```

I made a really simple example because all the socket thing is working. After I call the event `page:closed` on the client side, my application disconnect from socket and changes page. When I Come back to that `pageSocket`, it connects again,the child are forked (I made an `console.log` on the child, just to be sure) but, when `some:event` are emmited and the server tries to call `child.send` I got the following error:

```
Error: closed channel
```

I already tried to pass `SIGHUP`, `SIGKILL` and `SIGINT` as signals to the `.kill` method and tried to close the child from itself with `process.exit(0)`

Comment: Why don't leave the child process open in the first place? Keep it outside of the io.connection listener, and add the `socket.id` to the message you send to it, in order to keep track of clients.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks!